# Change src with javascript only one in a group of images

Tags: javascript, image, src

i am really new with JavaScript. I new to click an image, that image will change SRC and the others too.

This is the code:

```
<a href="#pduno"><img onclick="this.src='img/pduno.png';document.getElementsByClassName('imgdp').src='img/pddos.png'" class="imgdp" src="img/pduno.png" width="13" height="11" /></a> 
<a href="#pddos"><img onclick="this.src='img/pduno.png';document.getElementsByClassName('imgdp').src='img/pddos.png'" class="imgdp" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
<a href="#pddos"><img onclick="this.src='img/pduno.png';document.getElementsByClassName('imgdp').src='img/pddos.png'" class="imgdp" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
```

pduno.png is the "active" image and pddos.png is the "desactive" image.

Let's image I have 3 images pduno - pddos - pddos

When I click one of the 2 pddos, it change to pduno and the one that was pduno change to pddos. I mean, there will be only one image with pduno while the rest are pddos.

I am using this to create a scroll gallery. The pduno works to show what gallery is being showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for that (because you need to use some not-so-simple functions)

You can include it writing this code (no need to download anything):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
```

And then, I would do this:

```
<a href="#pddos"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pduno.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
<a href="#pddos"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
<a href="#pddos"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
```

In the HTML, I removed all the scripts, and moved them here:

```
<script>
$('.pdimg').click(function(){ //This registers the function with the click event
    $('.pdimg').attr('src', 'img/pddos.png'); //This resets the image to pddos
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/pddos.png'); //This sets the image to uno, 
                             // "this" will be the img that you clicked on.
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` will select a nodelist from the document, not a single element. To change the src attribute of each of the selected elements, you will have to loop over the list.

Also, to reset all images to pddos and then make one active, you can't set one to pduno and then reset all.